# When I should create separate Provider class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have class that process data. I have two options.
1. To registration it as Provider directly:

```
class GetServerData extends ChangeNotifier 
{
  String resultDate;
  getData() {
    resultDate = http.get(...);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

2. Сreate wrapper-provider class. And use it as Provider.

```
class ServerDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
    String resultDate;
    GetServerData getServerData = GetServerData();

   getData() {
    resultDate = getServerData.getData();
    notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

When I should prefer to use first variant and when second?